# Sync sticky notes between Windows 7 and Linux on Dual Boot System?

Tags: windows-7, linux, sync, fedora, sticky-notes

I love Windows 7's sticky notes, it really helps. Here's the issue though: I dual boot Windows 7 and Fedora Linux. Whichever OS I'm in is random, depending on what I'm wanting to do at the time. Therefore I can't rely on just keeping the notes in my "primary" OS and referencing it when needed

Does anybody know of a way to sync Windows 7's Sticky Notes with Fedora? Various Google searches haven't yielded much as they deal with primarily syncing between common OS's.

Comment: `%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt ` is the location of the stickynotes notes, you may be able to parse the notes out of it?

Comment: @Rob Its in some strange binary format, not easily parsable

Comment: Oh well, was worth a shot at least.

Answer (score 2):

So here is an idea you may want to explore:

I did a quick search but couldn't find the exe for the Sticky notes but you might be able to put that in Wine and running on your Fedora box.

You can then use dropbox to sync between Windows and Fedora.  You could use mklink to link to your dropbox so it updates automatically.

Comment: This is one of those "Sure it works, but ouch..." solutions. I would only do this as a last resort